# asp.net ImageButton CommandArgument

Tags: imagebutton

So I have a object PlayerList of type List and I am doing a foreach to fill a table. I want to add the ID of each player to the CommandArgument so when they click on the imagebutton, I know the ID of the player we need to work with. For some reason this is not working. CommandArgument is always returning empty string yet the collection has the ID when I debug and look into each player.

```
<% foreach (var Player in PlayerList)
{ %>
<tr>
    <td><asp:ImageButton Width="32px" Height="32px" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Player.ID")%>' ID="EditRecord" ImageUrl="../Images/edit.png" OnCommand="EditRecord_Click" runat="server" /></td> 
    <td><%=Player.FirstName %></td> 
    <td><%=Player.LastName %></td> 
    <td width="15%"><%=Player.Address %></td> 
    <td><%=Player.DOB %></td> 
    <td><%=Player.Parent1 %></td> 
    <td><%=Player.Parent1Phone %></td> 
    <td><%=Player.Parent1Email %></td> 
    <td><%=Player.Parent2 %></td> 
    <td><%=Player.Parent2Phone %></td> 
    <td><%=Player.Parent2Email %></td> 
</tr>
<%} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution myself. Instead of using a foreach loop, I added a Repeater.